# Changing the position of an image inside another image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, embed

I need your help please.
I'm working in Matlab and I have tow images one with size 256*256 and the other one with size 64*64. I want to embed the small image into the first one but i would like to control the position of the embedding process.
For example having the small image in the corner of the big image and then I want to change it in the middle ...
do you have any idea how ?
thank you

Comment: How do you plan to control the position?

Comment: I'm thinking about deplacing the small image to the left, right, top, botom... but I'm a little bit confused how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way using `ginput`, with which you select a number of points and get their x-y coordinates. Here the user selects a single point (so we use `ginput(1)`), which becomes the top-left corner of the small image, placed "inside" the big image. I suggest copying this exact code in a .m file and play around with it.

If you have questions please ask.

```
function PlaceImage

clear
clc
close all

%// Create figure and uielements
handles.fig = figure('Position',[440 400 500 230]);

handles.DispButton = uicontrol('Style','Pushbutton','Position',[20 70 80 40],'String','Select point','Callback',@PlaceImageCallback);

%// Set up big and small images
OriginalBigIm = imread('coins.png');

SmallIm = imread('circuit.tif');

SmallIm = imresize(SmallIm,[60 60]);


%// Get size of small image
[heightSmall,WidthSmall] = size(SmallIm);

imshow(OriginalBigIm,[]);


    function PlaceImageCallback(~,~)

        BigIm = OriginalBigIm;

        imshow(OriginalBigIm,[]);

        %// Select a point where to put the top-left corner of the small image
        [xTopLeft,yTopLeft] = ginput(1);

        xTopLeft = round(xTopLeft);
        yTopLeft = round(yTopLeft);

        %// Replace pixels in the big image with the small image
        BigIm(yTopLeft:yTopLeft+heightSmall-1,xTopLeft:xTopLeft+WidthSmall-1) = SmallIm;

        %// Display result
        imshow(BigIm,[]);
    end

end
```

And sample output after pressing the button. If you press it again the original image appears and you can thus change the position of the small image as you wish.

[image]

Comment: so did you try my suggestion @Youssi?

Comment: Hi @Benoit_11, thank you for your help, yes I tried your suggestion and it works very well. But do you think this could work with an invisible image? I mean small invisible image in the big one?
Thank you

Comment: ok great. If this helped that would be very kind of you to mark it as accepted by clicking the green checkmark beside it. As for your question, yes I think that would work. Although I'm not entirely sure of what you mean by "small invisible image in the big on". Can you give an example?

Comment: I mean like an invisible logo inserted in an image and changing its position by time

Comment: Oh do you mean a transparent image? Like a logo with a background we can see through?

Comment: No, I mean like invisible watermarking: inserting a mark in image, but this mark should be invisible